# Let $F$ be a finite field and $\tau$ an element of $F$. Prove that there exists $a,b\in F$ such that $\tau=a^2+b^2$.

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field and $\tau$ an element of $F$. Prove that there exists $a,b\in F$ such that $\tau=a^2+b^2$. It suffices to prove for the case $F=\mathbb{Z}_p$. How to prove?

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Every_element_of_a_finite_field_is_expressible_as_a_sum_of_two_squares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|F| = p^n$, where $p$ is a prime; and consider $\varphi : F\to F$ given by $x\mapsto x^2$.

1. If $p=2$, $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, so we're done.
2. If $p > 2$, check that $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y)$ iff $x = \pm y$, and hence (why?)
   $$
   |Im(\varphi)| \geq \frac{p^n+1}{2} := k
   $$
   For $z \in F$, consider $S:= \{z - \varphi(x) : x \in F\}$. Since $2k > p^n$, one has that $S\cap Im(\varphi) \neq \emptyset$, so we are done.